# How do I unlock a microsd card?

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have a locked microSD (locked by Nokia symbian phone). I forgot the password; how do I unlock it? I don't mind if I lose my data in microSD. I can't mount it.

[image: generic-multi-card shown in Disks]

Output of `mkdir ~/sd_mount && sudo mount /dev/sdb ~/sd_mount` and `sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: screenshot of terminal, no sign of any device other than the internal disk]

It's microSD, no physical lock like on SD card. I formatted it and lost all of the data, but the card is still locked.